# How to redirect output files of a program?

Tags: linux, files, output

I have the following distribution of files:

```
samuel@samuel-TM1607:~/Documents/Fisica/19-20/Radiactividad/Prácticas/Practicas-onteCarlo0/GAMMA/prueba$ ls ../
detector-1.in  GAMMA-Resultados  penmain-mac.x    prueba
detector.geo   NaI.mat           penmain-W32.exe
Fe.mat         penmain-linux.x   penmain-W64.exe
```

I want to run the "penmain-linux.x" which needs to read all the other files that are not executables and the ".in" as input. I  want all the output files to go to the folder "prueba".

I've already tried running it from "prueba" as follows:

```
samuel@samuel-TM1607:~/Documents/Fisica/19-20/Radiactividad/Prácticas/Practicas-onteCarlo0/GAMMA/prueba$ ../penmain-linux.x < ../detector-1.in
```

But I get

```
   Initialising PENGEOM ...
At line 275 of file pengeom.f (unit = 15, file = 'detector.geo')
Fortran runtime error: End of file
```

which I guess it is because the other input files which the program calls from inside are not in the "prueba" folder.

So how can I do it?

Thank you in advance!

EDIT:
If I run the program as it is I get all the files in the same folder as the image:

[image: Folder after running it.]

Comment: Is it important to you to execute the program from a child directory? Why not: `cd ..`; then run the program?

Comment: Did you write this program, or have its source code available, or have documentation for it? I'm wondering if it hard-codes the output filename in any way.

Comment: @JeffSchaller I did this because I saw an answer where to get all the files in the child folder he executed it from that child folder.

Comment: @JeffSchaller I didn't write the code. And I don't know what to hard-core the output file name would mean...

Comment: By "hard-code the output file" I meant whether the program wrote its own output files, which you want to go to the "prueba" folder. Does the program write files on its own, or does it print them to stdout for you to redirect?

Comment: @JeffSchaller It writes files on its own. I have edited the question and added a screenshot of the folder after running it.

Comment: I imagine a couple solutions to this problem. One could be to create symlinks inside the prueba folder to all of the files that the program wants to use. Another would be to execute the program above the prueba folder, then move the output files afterwards. Does either of those sound appealing?

Comment: @JeffSchaller I'll investigate about the symlinks and if not I guess I'll just do the second solution. Thanks a lot :D